# Передача двумерного массива по ссылке С++

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, параметры

Есть двумерный массив чисел. 
Int mass[15][20]
Нужно передать его в функцию так, чтобы изменение его в функции отражалось в main. После попыток разобраться поняла, что нужно как-то передавать по ссылке, но не могу сообразить как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте. Только скобочки не забудьте:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int (& mass)[15][20]) {
  mass[1][1] = 42;
}

int main() {
  int mass[15][20] = { 0 };
  f(mass);
  std::cout << mass[1][1] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::cout << mass[1][1] << std::endl; для чего нужна эта строчка? Попыталась запустить без нее, сработало вроде.

Comment: @Лера Это просто вывод результата. Если он вам не нужен, делайте без него.